# Center a box with image and floating text in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

how can i center a box with a picture and two headlines floating right of them?

```
  <div class="py-1 py-sm-5">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="img/logo_gross.png" class="mx-auto d-block col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-8 img-fluid float-sm-left" alt="Dennis Pfeiffer Asslar - Dienstleistung Professionell">
      <h1 class="text-center text-sm-left"><span class="text-red">dienstleistung</span><span class="text-blue">professionell</span></h1>
      <h1 class="text-center text-sm-left"><span class="text-red">dennis</span> <span class="text-blue">pfeiffer</span></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

At the moment, everything is aligned at the left screen, but i want it centered.
And NO, working with 2 x "col-6" ist no solution because it will not be really centered.

Comment: Can you put your code in a jsfiddle or codepen? And a link to the actual image or one with similar dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

Set the container to a `flex` display and set `justify-content` to `center`.

```
<div class="py-1 py-sm-5 d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="img/logo_gross.png" class="mx-auto d-block col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-8 img-fluid float-sm-left" alt="Dennis Pfeiffer Asslar - Dienstleistung Professionell">
    <h1 class="text-center text-sm-left"><span class="text-red">dienstleistung</span><span class="text-blue">professionell</span></h1>
    <h1 class="text-center text-sm-left"><span class="text-red">dennis</span> <span class="text-blue">pfeiffer</span></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This want work.
i want the box with centered with text right of the image, not above.